# Azure AD not showing Networks when Enabling Directory Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-network

I am attempting to link my Azure AD to a Network to enable Azure Directory Services. I have created a network but every time I try to enable the Azure Directory Services no networks show up under the 'CONNECT DOMAIN SERVICES TO THIS VIRTUAL NETWORK' dropdown menu. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Does your virtual network create in new portal?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you create your virtual network in Azure new portal(ARM module).
For now, Azure AD Domain Services **cannot be enabled in virtual networks created using Azure Resource Manager**.
In your scenario, I think we should use **VNet peering** or **site-to-site** VPN to connect classic Vnet and ARM vnet. You can connect a Resource Manager-based virtual network to the Azure classic virtual network in which you have enabled Azure AD Domain Services. This connection enables you to use the managed domain with your workloads deployed in the Resource Manager-based virtual network.
[image]

More information about select a virtual network for AD DS, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-networking).

Comment: Was your issue resolved?  Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you would like further assistance, also if it helps, please don't forget to mark it as an answer, thanks